# How to make a User Interface of my android application

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I am trying to make android application which display newsfeeds  through web,I have done with all functionality, as I programmed well but not design well I am getting problem to desing UI of my Application,I donot have enough idea how to do this, whether I use relative layout,or linear layout etc, Would you suggest me the way how can I design UI in xml file, I would be very grateful to you[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the UI Guidelines from [Android Dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html). Take the trainings provided there if you require. Read the Quick Overview page as well to cover important aspects.

... and here is a [resource listing page](http://spyrestudios.com/40-brilliant-android-mobile-app-user-interfaces/) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to learn android layouts. Try with some examples on each layouts. People here can help you if you have any issue with layouts, but don't expect someone to design and code for you.

OK . I would suggest you to use these layouts for this screen

1. Use ActionbarActivity with menu items ( action icon)
2. Search view or Edit text
3. Image view
4. Text view
5. Vertical Linearlayout with Imageview and Text view
6. Grid view with text view items.